# Javascript - Matching a hyphen in regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match a string using regex (of which I am new to) but I can't get it to match.

These should be accepted:

- GT-00-TRE
- KK-10-HUH
- JU-05-OPR

These should not:

- HTH-00-AS
- HM-99-ASD
- NM-05-AK

So the pattern goes 2 letters, hyphen, 2 digits (between 00 and 11 inclusive), hyphen, 3 letters.

So far the best I can come up with is:

```
var thePattern = /^[a-z]{2}[-][00-11][-][a-z]{3}$/gi;
```

I can't help but feel that I'm pretty close.

Can anyone give me any pointers?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should be what you need:

```
var thePattern = /^[a-z]{2}[-](0\d|1[0-1])[-][a-z]{3}$/gi;
```

In order to do a range 00-11, you have to say "(0 followed by 0-9) or (1 followed by 0 or 1)". This is because specifying a range within `[]` only works for single digits. Luckily your case is pretty simple, otherwise it could get quite complex to work around that.

Comment: Awesome, that worked perfectly! Not to be a pain, but would you mind explaining what parts were wrong and why? I don't wanna just be given an answer without knowing what it does :).

Comment: If I can help: something in square brackets means a character class, it represents a single character! eg [0-5] means any **single** digit between 0 and 5, [a-q] means any lowercase letter from a to q. There's no such thing as [00-11], you need to specify the exact syntax of the characters

Comment: Cheers dfsq! Gabber I appreciate the input, being new to regex is proving to be a slight headache but I can imagine it will be pretty useful in the future, thanks for clearing that up!

Comment: To add to others, the sequences in `[]` are text based, not number based. `[0-9]` means match any digits between 0 and 9, not any number. Bit of a weird distinction, but it means you cant say `[0-10]` because 10 is not a digit.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is OK, but for one thing: the digits matching is a bit more complex

```
(0\d|10|11)
```

you want to match a zero followed by a digit (`\d`) OR (`|`) a ten OR a eleven.

Something in square brackets represents just a *single* character in a range. `[0-5]` means any single digit between 0 and 5, `[a-q]` means any lowercase letter from a to q. There's no such thing as `[00-11]` because it would require to work on more than one character at a time.